Quadratics with common roots - theorem about the non-common root.
In 1916 on the Algebra (pass) examination for Matriculation, set by the University of Melbourne the following question was posed:
Prove that if $ax^2+bx+c=0$ has a root in common with $bx^2+cx+a=0$ then its other root satisfies $a^2bx^2+ax(2b^2-ac)+a^3+b^3-abc=0$.
Finding an expression for the common root is not too difficult using simultaneous equations with $x$ and $x^2$ being the unknowns: $x=\frac{a^2-bc}{b^2-ac}$. It is at this point that I get stuck and wonder if there is a simple (or "nice") way to proceed.
One idea I had (that has gone nowhere) was to write the two roots of $ax^2+bx+c=0$ as $x=p$ and $x=q$ where $p=\frac{a^2-bc}{b^2-ac}$.
Using Vieta's formulas $p+q=\frac{-b}{a}$ and $pq=\frac{c}{a}$, this would mean $q=\frac{-b}{a}-\frac{a^2-bc}{b^2-ac}$ or $q=\frac{c}{a} \times \frac{b^2-ac}{a^2-bc}$.
However, as much as I tried, after substitution into $a^2bx+ax(2b^2-ac)+a^3+b^3-abc$ I could not find a way to make the expression $0$.
Can anyone suggest a better approach?

The expression $a^2bx+ax(2b^2-ac)+a^3+b^3-abc=0$ doesn't seem to be correct. If $a=b=1$ and $c=-2$ then the first quadratic is $x^2+x-2$ with roots $-2$ and $1$, and the second quadratic is $x^2 -2x + 1 = (x-1)^2$. But if $a=b=1$ and $c=-2$ is plugged in into the expression for the other root, it evaluates to $5x+4=0$.

Thanks @RandyMarsh. I was beginning to doubt it myself but this is what the exam paper said and I can't find any notice of corrections (that said, official solutions were never released either). If that is the case, is there a way to improve the expression to make it valid?

I suggest that the expression should be $a^2bx^2+ ax(....$. [I couldn't see why the $x$'s weren't gathered together.]

Oh dear... thanks everyone for such a woeful oversight on my part. Correcting now.

The coefficients are real?

@Sahaj I think that is a fair assumption given this was the Pass not Honours exam paper but it is never stated. Does it make a difference though?

I will call $a^2bx^2+ax(2b^2-ac)+a^3+b^3-abc$ as 'the expression'.
I used WolframAlpha to evaluate the expression at certain values of $x$, so this might not be the most feasible method for calculation by hand.
First note that if $x=0$ is a root then the other root is $-b/a$ which, when plugged into the expression, evaluates to $a^3$. Since we implicitly assume $a\neq 0$ we can assume that 0 is not a root.
Therefore multiply $ax^2+bx+c = 0$ with $x$ to obtain $ax^3+bx^2+cx = 0$. Using the second quadratic we obtain $ax^3 - a = 0$, therefore $x=1$ is the common root.
Now from Vieta's formulas it follows quite easily that $x=-\frac{b}{a}-1$ is the other root. When the expression is evaluated for this value of $x$ we obtain $a^2(a+b+c)$.
Now recall that $x=1$ solves $ax^2+bx+c=0$, therefore $a+b+c=0$. Hence $x=-\frac{b}{a}-1$ satisfies the expression.

Very nice. I had worked out that the other root was a cube root of unity but for some reason testing $x=1$ did not occur to me. So thanks.

Determining the value of the common root is not needed. Directly substituting $x=-b/a-p$ gives the same type of factorization as in the answer in the more general form $a^2(bp^2+cp+a)$. The second factor vanishes by the common root assumption.

Thanks @EeroHakavuori. Can you elaborate on this somewhat, perhaps as an answer? I think this has a lot of merit as both an idea and a method of solution.

It's the same method, except it doesn't require arguing that one solution is $x=1$. If you assume that $p$ is the common solution, then $\frac{-b}{a}-p$ is the other solution. Now you plug this into the expression and after simplifying obtain $a^2(bp^2+cp+a)$. The second factor is zero because $p$ is a solution to that quadratic.
